# Using OrderBy on an Umbraco Node list with C#

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have a list in C# of Umbraco nodes. I can Order these successfully using some of the top-level properites built into the node class (e.g. node.Name) but when I'm trying to get some of the dynamic properties using the GetProperty() function I'm getting a NullReferenceException.

Code:

`nodes = nodes.OrderBy(n => n.GetProperty("fromPrice").ToString()).ToList();`

Replacing `n.GetProperty("fromPrice").ToString()` with `n.Name` works, but I don't want to sort by this.

Exception message:

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Not entirely sure what that means. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally this means the node it is iterating over doesnt have that property. You should filter by document type first beforehand and filter out any where that property is null. Then sort.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I have already done this, that's where the original list has come from. The properties are all there for each node.

Comment: @DeclanTyson... apparently not.

Comment: @spender I call upon the exact same method outside of the OrderBy(), and it returns as expected.

Comment: @DeclanTyson So, if, before the line `nodes.OrderBy(n => n.GetProperty("fromPrice").ToString()).ToList();` you run the statement `nodes.Select(n => n.GetProperty("fromPrice").ToString()).ToList();`, you get no error? You're absolutely sure about that?

Comment: What about the statement `nodes.Count(n => n==null||n.GetProperty("fromPrice")==null)`? That definitely returns zero?

Comment: @spender Select worked fine, but the count returned 1. It turns out there was a node in the recycle bin that was being included in the list! Thanks very much for your help

Comment: @spender - are you going to add an answer so it can be upvoted?

Comment: @amelvin No, because I only gave debugging tips... I didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could benefit from a Where clause in your query, something like this (writting from my memory, not tested)

```
var nodes = nodes.Where(x => x.GetProperty("fromPrice") != null).OrderBy(n => n.GetProperty("fromPrice").Value);
```

This should first filter out the nodes which haven't got a property called `"fromPrice"` and then perform the ordering. When working with the `Node` object, I don't think you have to call `ToString()`, simply just get the `Value` instead.

Let me know how this works :-)

Comment: This is similar advice that @spender gave me that eventually solved the problem.